# R performance improvement

Tags: r, performance

I want to solve a statistical problem with R. I already have a working approach, but it takes too much time to get it through. Maybe someone of you has an idea how to program smarter, possibly without loops.
There is a field "Orders". Orders[, 1] contain the order number and Orders[, 2: 200] contain the article numbers ordered in the order.
I would like to fill in the field "Result". In Result[, 1] are all article numbers. The field to be filled is Result[, 2: 1000] with article numbers, which were purchased together with Result[, 1].
Since both (the i- and j-loop) goes up to more than 100000, the whole course takes ... Projected about 60 days. Does anyone have an idea to improve the performance?
My working code is:

```
for (i in 1:length(Result$Artiklenumber)) {
  for (j in 1:length(Orders$Ordernumber)) {
    if (length(which(Orders[j,]==Result[i,1])) == 0){
      next
    }
    for (k in 2:(min(which(is.na(Orders[j,])))-1) ) { 
      if ( Orders[j,k]!=Result[i,1] ){
        Result[i,min(which(is.na(Result[i,])))] <- Orders[j,k]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example for "Orders":

```
0011566702  10131925    10131927    10136287    10136292    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
0011677781  16320   16800   16810   18270   18280   807310  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
0011724272  204520  204590  1083740 1083880 1111150 1111640 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
0011760684  10149459    10149460    10149461    10149462    10149463    10149464    10149465    10149466    10149467    10149468    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
0011784677  10151542    10151543    10151545    10151549    10151551    10151552    10151555    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
0011804598  10107450    10123183    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
0011811507  31540   4028890 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
0011813716  6670    16800   10050265    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
0011818851  16800   16810   807310  4229030 10050265    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Example for "Result":

```
16610   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
16620   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
16630   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
16670   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
16710   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
16720   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
16740   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
16800   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
16810   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
16820   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: Can you share your data with dput() so it can be reproduced without issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution which works without loops. First I generate some small test data:

```
orders = cbind(1001:1008, matrix(sample(1:6, 8*3, replace=TRUE), 8, 3))
orders[1:2, 4] = orders[4, 3:4] = NA
> orders 
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 1001    2    4   NA
[2,] 1002    2    3   NA
...
```

then I extract the unique articles:

```
articles = unique(as.vector(orders[, -1]))
```

Finally I create a function which finds articles together in some basket and apply it:

```
findBaskets = function(article) {
  ordersIncludingArticle = apply(orders[, -1] == article, 1, any)
  articlesTogether = unique(as.vector(orders[ordersIncludingArticle, -1]))
  articlesTogether[articlesTogether != article & !is.na(articlesTogether)]
}

sapply(articles, findBaskets)
```

However, this gives the solution in list format:

```
> res = sapply(articles, findBaskets)
> names(res) = articles
> res 
$`2`
[1] 4 6 3 5 1

$`6`
[1] 3 2 1 5
...
```

To put this into an array you can create an empty matrix with the right dimensions and then fill the matrix by a loop or so. This should for sure not hurt the performance.

Comment: fantastic, with this function the running time is reduced to 17 hours (from 60 days...) Thanks a lot lambruscoAcido

Comment: @BenjaminSchaaf - I think you can do something like "accept the answer" or whatever makes sense for you, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Bests, lA